# Wpf binding list of custom objects to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Hello I want to bind a list of custom object to a ListBox in WPF.
I have the next code:

```
private List<User> users = new List<User>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.users = User.GetAllUsersFromFile();

    this.listBox.DataContext = users;
    this.listBox.ItemsSource = users;
}
```

And the XML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
</ListBox>
```

And the User class:

```
private string name;
private byte[] avatar;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value.Any(c => c == ' '))
            throw new Exception("Invalid name. (It cannot contain spaces)");

        this.name = value;
    }
}

public byte[] Avatar
{
    get
    {
        return this.avatar;
    }
    set
    {
        this.avatar = value;
    }
}
```

The initial list is showing as expected , but if new items are added to the list (or deleted) the list is not updating.

Comment: Use `ObservableCollection<User> users` and you should be fine.

Comment: Is the list dynamic or static?

Comment: Why `this.listBox.DataContext = users;`? That doesn't serve any purpose. Ten minutes reading documentation gets you farther than two days assigning arbitrary values to random properties.

Answer (score 0):

As Sinatr pointed out I used ObservableCollection and it worked as expected.
Thanks.